# LocalReAlloc failing

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

Ok, I give up. What am I doing wrong? I have a simple Windows C Console App that does this:

```
int buflen = 10;
PUCHAR ptr = LocalAlloc(LPTR, buflen);  // returns valid address
buflen = 20;
ptr = LocalReAlloc(ptr, buflen, 0); // returns NULL with GetLastError() = 8
```

I have also tried this with the same results:

```
ptr = LocalReAlloc(ptr, buflen, LPTR);
```

Is there some secret I need to know about LocalReAlloc?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using [LocalAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[LocalReAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Their msdn pages clearly state that they are present only for compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your `LocalAlloc` you are passing the `LMEM_FIXED` flag (it is included in `LMEM_PTR`).  Because of that `LocalReAlloc` [can only re-allocate the memory in place:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If the memory is a locked LMEM_MOVEABLE memory block or a LMEM_FIXED
>   memory block and this flag is not specified, the memory can only be
>   reallocated in place.

This means that `LocalReAlloc` is not allowed to change the value of the pointer it returns.  If the local heap has free memory right next to the existing pointer it can  it can expand the allocation.  Because the memory is fixed, it is prevented from allocated a new block.

So in your case `LocalReAlloc` is unabled to re-allocte in place and returns the best error it can which is 8 - ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY.

So what's the solution?  Don't use LocalAlloc!  It only exists for Win16 and some old API support.  Use malloc()/realloc() which don't have this issue.

Comment: Pass `LMEM_MOVEABLE` to say "I know this was allocated as `LMEM_FIXED`, but I would like you to move it anyway. Trust me on this."

Comment: That was the ticket, thanks! I would never have guessed that from the documentation.